# Find existing data driven subscription in reportserver

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am in need of a query to identify all data driven subscriptions in SSRS.  Does anyone know if that is possible?  I looked into subscription table and I only see EVENTTYPE = 'Timed Subscription'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should provide a list of subscriptions that are data-driven.

```
SELECT  s.*
FROM dbo.Subscriptions AS s 
WHERE s.DataSettings IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use queries to the Report Server's database if you can avoid it. There are no guarantees that it will stay the same between versions and, in the worst case, querying it could actually interfere with Report Server operations.

Use the API instead, either by writing the appropriate code to call the web services in a program or using RS.exe (See [Script with the rs.exe Utility and the Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152874.aspx)).

Below is a script for use with RS.exe that you should be able to easily adapt to your needs. You should run this under a user account that is an administrator of the Report Server.

```
Public Const vbTab As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.vbTab

Public Function ListCatalogItems() As [CatalogItem]()
    Dim items As [CatalogItem]() = Nothing

    Try
        items = rs.ListChildren("/", true)
    Catch ex As System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Detail.InnerXml)
    Catch e as Exception
        Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try

    Return items
End Function

Public Function GetSubscriptions(itemPath As String) As [Subscription]()
    Dim subscriptions As [Subscription]() = Nothing

    Try
        subscriptions = rs.ListSubscriptions(itemPath, Nothing)
    Catch ex As System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Detail.InnerXml)
    Catch e as Exception
        Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try

    Return subscriptions
End Function

'rs -i GetSubscriptions.rsvb -s http://MyReportServer/ReportServer
Public Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Getting list of items from server...")

    Dim items As [CatalogItem]() = ListCatalogItems()

    If items Is Nothing OrElse items.Length = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}There are no folders to process.", vbTab))
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Checking Items for subscriptions...")
        For Each item As [CatalogItem] In items
            If item.Type = ItemTypeEnum.Report
                Dim subscriptions As [Subscription]() = GetSubscriptions(item.Path)
                For Each subscriptionItem As [Subscription] In subscriptions
                    Dim subscriptionType As String = "Subscription"

                    If subscriptionItem.IsDataDriven = True Then
                        subscriptionType = "Data driven subscription"
                    End If

                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2} owned by {3} on report {4}.", vbTab, subscriptionType, subscriptionItem.SubscriptionID, 

subscriptionItem.Owner, subscriptionItem.Report))
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Console.WriteLine("Done.")
    Console.WriteLine()
End Sub
```